# Component mounted but template tags not rendered in production environment (but rendered in development): Nuxtjs Vuejs Vuetifyjs Rollupjs

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js, nuxt.js, rollupjs

### Synonypsis

Please allow me to explain what is going on. I did the following:

1. made custom Vue components using Vuetify components
2. made a custom Vue component using these Vuetify components and the custom components from (1)
3. used rollupjs to bundle these components together
4. published these components on npm
5. deployed to GitLab pages an example of the "main" component from (2), using the local version of the component (rather than the one from npm)
6. made a new nuxt project
7. dockerized it
8. I install my package from (4) and use it
9. deployed this test repository on GitLab pages

What happened that inspired this post:
1. On the component's repository GitLab page (step 5 from above), the component is both rendered and mounted
2. On the test repository GitLab page (step 9 from above), the component is **mounted** but the template is not rendered (e.g. it is like its template tag `<my-component></my-component>`)
3. In the test repository, using docker in development everything is ok
4. In the test repository the component is mounted but not rendered

### Details

The offending component is called `VRecordsTable` from the package `valpha`. It is a wrapper of the Vuetify component `VDataTable` and adds custom slots, logic and a few other components. (links below).

The component is mounted in production (the data is there, reactive via vuex store also works), but the html is as follows:

```html
<v-col><v-data-table page="0" items-per-page="5" items="record1,record2,record3,record4,record5,record6,record7,record8,record9" calculate-widths="true" fixed-header="" headers-length="7"></v-data-table></v-col>
```

Here is an image from the linked test repo below showing what I mean:

[image]

Notice, the component is mounted with data all there, but unlike all the other components, it doesn't have a drop down to see the internal components.

I'm not sure where I went wrong, at the bottom of this post is quick links to the repo of both the component and the test repo, in addition to useful files like `rollup.config.js`

### Useful commands

For docker in the test repo please use:

```sh
# dev
docker-compose -f docker-compose.development.yml build
docker-compose -f docker-compose.development.yml up
docker-compose -f docker-compose.development.yml down

# prod
docker-compose -f docker-compose.production.yml build
docker-compose -f docker-compose.production.yml up
docker-compose -f docker-compose.production.yml down
```

### Links

- component repo:

  - [npm package of component](https://www.npmjs.com/package/valpha)
  - [gitlab page of the component](https://sumneuron.gitlab.io/valpha)
  - [git repository of component](https://www.npmjs.com/package/valpha)
  - [rollup.config.js of component](https://gitlab.com/SumNeuron/valpha/blob/master/rollup.config.js)
  - [package.json file of component](https://gitlab.com/SumNeuron/valpha/blob/master/package.json)
  - [nuxt.config.js of component's repo](https://gitlab.com/SumNeuron/valpha/blob/master/nuxt.config.js)
  - [entry.js used by rollup.config.js](https://gitlab.com/SumNeuron/valpha/blob/master/entry.js)
  - [offending component `VRecordsTable`](https://gitlab.com/SumNeuron/valpha/blob/master/components/VRecordsTable.vue)
- test repo

  - [gitlab page of the test repo](https://sumneuron.gitlab.io/test-valpha)
  - [test repo](https://gitlab.com/sumneuron/test-valpha)

### Hunchs

- something with `npm run start` vs `npm run dev` / how nuxt is built is the issue?
- something with how I configured rollup.config.js is the issue?
- something with vuetify is the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify-loader/issues/70

test-valpha is using vuetify-loader but valpha isn't, so the required vuetify components aren't automatically imported. Normally you'd get warnings about this but [nuxt suppresses warnings in production mode](https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-vue-config/) and the @nuxtjs/vuetify module [only uses vuetify-loader in production mode](https://github.com/nuxt-community/vuetify-module/blob/3ce0a7d51dfb95f9e312feffe6faae40469fe37d/src/options.ts#L45) for some reason so everything seems to be working fine during development.

Some solutions are listed in the github issue:

- Import the required components in `valpha` (see below) AND
- Always use vuetify-loader by [setting treeShake to true](https://github.com/nuxt-community/vuetify-module#treeshake) in test-valpha

OR

- Don't use vuetify-loader in test-valpha (`treeShake: false`)

**Importing components**

If the library was using webpack you'd just have to install vuetify-loader, but there isn't anything similar for rollup so you need to add them manually [as described in the documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/a-la-carte#markup-html-a-la-carte-destructuring):

```html
<template>
  <v-card>
    <v-card-title>...</v-card-title>
    <v-card-text>...</v-card-text>
  </v-card>
</template>

<script>
  import { VCard, VCardText, VCardTitle } from 'vuetify/lib'

  export default {
    components: {
      VCard,
      VCardText,
      VCardTitle,
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: 1st thank you. Whenever I begin to think I am starting to know what I’m doing, it turns out I don’t :p because I am still learning could you please provide the changes to the configuration for valpha and how to set treeshaking? I’ve tried using vuetify a la carte in nuxt and always mess it up and struggle. If you do I’ll add a bounty and reward you

Comment: So I added the relevant components and tried `npm run r:build` in valpha, the result was that esm and umd build ok (complained about circular dependencies from vuetify, though) and for `unpkg` (creates `.min.js`) i get `[!] TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined` where `TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined: at ~/Projects/valpha/node_modules/rollup/dist/rollup.js:14802:55`

Comment: Well it seems the `.min` isn't needed... so your solution works (although if you could figure out the `.min` I believe it would be a more encompassing answer.  Also, it may be worth adding a specific documentation page for those building components on top of vuetify ^^.

Comment: one more follow up question, in a nuxt project using vuetify, `vskeletonloader` doesn't show in production, but all the other components do. Is this related to treeshaking somehow? despite everything else rendering?

Comment: That's probably from `rollup-plugin-uglify-es` which hasn't been updated since 2017, you should use terser instead.

> vskeletonloader doesn't show in production

I don't know, could be related to SSR. If you disable silent mode you'll get more information.

Comment: If you don't mind could you help with an adjacent issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59158339/vuetify-a-la-carte-rollup-component-complains-when-used-in-static-html-file